# Macro Missing Type Specifier with Static Variadic

Tags: c++11, templates, macros, variadic

I am attempting to automatically register data types against a factory. The first non-generalized version worked, but cannot define the registration macro since the factory was changed to a variadic. The compile error is...

> error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Not: C++ does
>   not support default-int.

```
#define GH_FACTORY_GET_LICENSE_FACTORY  \
    Factory<ILicenseManager, bool>::getFactory();

#define GH_FACTORY_REGISTER_LICENSE_MANAGER( ) \
    Factory<ILicenseManager, bool>::getFactory().registerType();
```

Example 1

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        Factory<gh::license::ILicenseManager, bool>::getFactory().registerType();
    }

    ~A() {}
};

static class A foo;
```

Example 2

```
GH_FACTORY_REGISTER_LICENSE_MANAGER;
```

When using

> GH_FACTORY_GET_LICENSE_FACTORY

and

> GH_FACTORY_REGISTER_LICENSE_MANAGER

in local scope it builds, but when using

> GH_FACTORY_REGISTER_LICENSE_MANAGER

in global scope it doesn't build (looks like the class is undefined?). Any ideas? Would love to understand why this happens.

Comment: `GH_FACTORY_REGISTER_LICENSE_MANAGER` expands into a function call expression, so you cannot put it at global scope on its own. You could use one of the usual tricks with static object initializers to call it at start-up though, but beware of the Static Initialization Order Fiasco.

Comment: D'oh! Yes the initial implementation declared a static object in the macro. Silly me